# regex for matching two or more numbers, then one 'x', then two or more numbers

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, strpos

I'm having trouble constructing this regex. I need a strpos or a preg_match that will match the following pattern: `00x00.` where the '0's are any number(s), and x is upper or lowercase, then a period.

I know I can do \d for numbers, but don't know how to specify two or more numbers. I know I can do [xX] for either upper or lowercase 'x', and I'm lost on the period.

I've tried this:

```
preg_match ( '/\\d[xX]\\d\./', $string )
```

but that isn't working.

I'd prefer to do it with a strpos, but either is fine.

EDIT - The period is optional; it's just added security. But I'm not sure if it's possible to match it not knowing how many numbers are between the 'x' and the period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like so: `\d{2,}[Xx]\d{2,}\.` will match two or more digits, an `x` (ignoring case) and two more digits and a period.

If that is all you want to match, I would recommend adding the anchor tags: `^\d{2,}[Xx]\d{2,}\.$`. This will instruct the regex engine to match exactly that.

So in short, this `\d{2,}[Xx]\d{2,}\.` will match `foo bar 000X00 foo bar` but this: `` `^\d{2,}[Xx]\d{2,}\.$ `` will match only `000X00` and nothing else (so it will fail for my previous example).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I'll try this out real quick.

Comment: @Thom: You're welcome. I have added some more detail to my response. Also, I am not a PHP guy, but why do you need an extra `\\`?

Comment: I didn't need the extra backslash. Was looking at JS regexes and got mixed up. Both of your examples work just as needed. Thanks very much for your help and your explanation!